# Tapestry: How to pass an Object using t:context

Tags: tapestry

I am using an eventLink. I can pass String and other primitive types using t:context. But I want to pass a whole Object using t:context. I get the error "Could not find a coercion from type java.lang.String to type test.ViewUsers". I am using valueEncoder but it is not called.

Here is my tml file

```
<table width="100%" t:type="grid" t:id="list" t:source="users" t:row="rowUser" encoder="encoder"

    t:model="beanModel"

    t:add="action"

    t:zone="^"

 >

   <p:actionCell >

   <a t:type="eventLink" t:event="review" t:context="[rowUser]" href="#" encoder="encoder">

            Testing

   </a>
```

Here is my Java file. The valueEncoder is not called. The logger.error did not output anything.

```
boolean onReview(ViewUsers object) {

    logger.error("Testing. Inside onReview");

     return false;

}



public ValueEncoder<ViewUsers> getEncoder()

{

    return new ValueEncoder<ViewUsers>()

    {

     @Override

      public String toClient(ViewUsers user)

       {

                logger.error("Testing. Inside toClient");

                if(user == null)

                {

                      return null;

                }

              return user.getId().toString();

         }

        @Override

        public ViewUsers toValue(String clientValue)

       {

               logger.error("Testing. Inside toValue");

              for(ViewUsers user : users)

              { 

                    if(user.getId().toString().equals(clientValue))

                    {

                            return user;

                     }

                 }

               return null;

          }

      };

 }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Contribute](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-configuration.html) a [ValueEncoderFactory](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/ValueEncoderFactory.html) to the [ValueEncoderSource](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/ValueEncoderSource.html)